# Linux batch rename files

Tags: linux, rename, bulk

I am going to rename image files and pdf files in a folder in Linux.

It should be recursively as some files are in sub-sub folder.

Current file name pattern is like:

```
an-yt-h-in-g-123word-123456-anything.jpg (.png .pdf)
```

My goal pattern is

```
123456-anything.jpg (.png .pdf)
```

In a short, I want to remove everything before `-NumberString-`, and keep everything afterwards (includes the `NumberString`).

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you read the tag info of [tag:batch-file]? I assume not as you would know it is related to Windows otherwise...

Comment: thanks for pick it up. I typed "batch", and it auto come up with batch-file, it's a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command will check position of last "number string" and output the sub string from this position to the end. You can change `ls` command to something else.

`ls | awk -F '-' '{ for(i=NF; i>=0; i--) { if (match($i, /^[0-9]+$/)) { print $i; for (j=i+1; j<=NF; j++){ printf "-%s" ,$j }; print "\n" } } }' $1 ORS=""`

Answer (score 1):

If all your files are named strictly as you said, you may use the command

```
echo $s | awk -F'-' '{printf "%s-%s", $5, $6}'
```

to get the new name, assuming that the original filename is held by `s`.

The renaming can be done simply with `mv` like

```
mv $s $(echo $s | awk -F'-' '{printf "%s-%s", $5, $6}')
```

where `s` is the original filename as well.

Comment: Thanks PJ. I did not explain clearly. The current file name pattern could be any length. It's like x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-xxxx-123456-xxxxx.jpg.

Comment: The last 2 fields regardless of number of hyphens would be `awk -F'-' '{printf "%s-%s", $(NF-1), $(NF)}'`

Comment: Right, @indiv 's answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

an-yt-h-in-g-123word-123456-anything.jpg

For a flat directory of jpegs:

```
rename 's/.*-[0-9]+-[A-Za-z]+\./\1-\2/.' *.jpg
```

For recursively visiting the current dir:

```
find . \(-name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.pdf" \) -exec rename 's/.*-[0-9]+-[A-Za-z]+\./\1-\2/.' {} ";"
```